# VB.NET common server controls and

Tags: html, css, vb.net

Attach the Main.css and Request.css style sheets to the Request web page. Make sure
that the link element for the Main.css sheet precedes the one for the Request.css sheet
so rules in the Request sheet can override rules in the Main sheet.

Comment: Did you have a question that you would like to ask about that?

Comment: yes. how to do it

Comment: Are you asking how to put `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/Main.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/Request.css" />` (adjust the file locations as required) in the `<head>` section of the HTML?